# Emit values every 250ms similar to debouceTime() but without the delay

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a heavy operation that re-arranges many DOM elements when the window is resized.

So I've been using `debounceTime(250ms)` to create a delay before updating the components. This works well unless the user resizes the window continuously. For example; if I resize the window wider very slowly for 10 seconds the observable will not emit any values. The `debounceTime(250ms)` only emits a value after 250ms has past without any new values.

I need an operator that will emit at least 1 value every 250ms similar to `debounceTime()` so that the user receives some feedback while resizing the window.

Here is an example component:

```
 @Component({....})
 public class ResizeComponent {
      private readonly widthChange: Subject<number> = new ReplaySubject(1);

      public constructor(private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
           this.widthChange.pipe(debounceTime(250)).subscribe((width: number) => {
              // do resize work here
           });
      }

      @HostListener('window:resize')
      public resize() {
           this.widthChange.next(this.elRef.nativeElement.clientWidth);
      }
}
```

**Question:**

The above will handle a window resize only after the user has stopped resizing for 250ms. How can I handle a resize every 250ms and also handle the last resize value.

Comment: I think this one https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/sampleTime is the one you are looking for. With distinctUntilChanged

Comment: I don't think that sampleTime is a good fit. It'll keep emitting values every 250ms which my really become a problem. You're probably looking for throttle or debounce

Comment: `distinctUntilChanged` will not emit until there is a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining 2 operators.

- sampleTime(250)
- distinctUntilChanged()

```js
observable.pipe(sampleTime(250), distinctUntilChanged(),
).subscribe(() => {
  ...
});
```